# Basic JAX-RS servlet in OSGi 4.2 environment

Tags: jersey, osgi, jax-rs

What is the simplest recipe to create a basic JAX-RS environment in an OSGi 4 container, without resorting to heavyweight solutions like Apache CXF.

Although it seems to me that registering a Jersey container servlet with the `HttpService` should do the trick, I have not been able piece together a collection of just a few bundles that does just that.

This is the essence of my bundle Activator, where the `Resources` class implements the `Application` interface to resolve which classes have JAX-RS annotations:

```java
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    // Find the HttpService
    ServiceReference ref = context.getServiceReference(HttpService.class.getName());
    HttpService service = (HttpService) context.getService(ref);    

    // Register a Jersey container
    ServletContainer servlet = new ServletContainer(new Resources());
    service.registerServlet("/services", servlet, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amdatu delivers a few opensource RESTful service bundles, including a JAX-RS solution based on Apache Wink.

See http://amdatu.org/components/web.html for a description and a [tutorial video](http://amdatu.org/howto/createwebapp.html) how to create a basic REST resource.

Comment: the links are broken

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sample application that works with Jersey: https://source.everit.biz/svn/everit-osgi/trunk/samples/jaxrs/

After running mvn install you will see the runnable equinox container with Jetty at target/eosgi-testing-dist/.... You can find which bundles were used in the lib folder.

It uses this solution: https://source.everit.biz/svn/everit-osgi/trunk/remote/jersey/

An here is the simplest code snippet that does the trick based on the solution above (myObj is the object that contains the annotations):

```
javax.ws.rs.core.Application application = new DefaultResourceConfig();
application.getSingletons().add(myObj);

com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer servletContainer =
       new ServletContainer(application);

Hashtable<String, String> initParams = new Hashtable<String, String>();
initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
httpService.registerServlet("/rest", servletContainer, initParams, null);
```

Note that "initparams.put" is useful if you want to have features like JSON transformation.

**update**

User/pass for SVN links: guest/guest

The remote-jersey project is not maintained anymore, but still available on github, too: https://github.com/everit-org/osgi-remote-jersey

Comment: The svn links are dead.

Comment: @Jmini SVN links work, but ask for user/pass. Updated the description with user-pass and also the remote-jersey is available on github, so added that link as well. Please note, that since the answer there were many other solutions, even there is a specification in the OSGi Compendium how to offer REST Services.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick: https://github.com/hstaudacher/osgi-jax-rs-connector

Using the publisher from this project you will be able to register your OSGi service as RESTful web services by simply registering them as OSGi services ;)

Answer (score 0):

What helped me is following article: [Setting Up JAX-RS for Equinox OSGI](https://dzone.com/articles/setting-up-jax-rs-for-equinox-osgi)

The key points are:

- The jersey resource configuration (`@Path`, `@Provider` anotated classes) needs to be registered  manually with a `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig`.
- All other configuration options (jersey auto discovery with `javax.ws.rs.Application` or `jersey.config.server.provider.packages`) will fail because Jersey server will not be able to scan them in Equinox.
- Instanciate the `ServletContainer` in the bundle where the resource configuration are located.